# Deep Omit with typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to maintain type coverage on a function that deeply removes all instances of a key in an object?

My function looks like this.

```
function omitDeep<T extends object>(obj: T, key: string): TWithoutProvidedKey {
  return JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(obj),
    (key: string, value: any) => key === "__typename" ? undefined : value
  );
}
```

Is there any way to make `TWithoutProvidedKey` a reality?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This can easily be done, you just need to use mapped types to recurse down the properties:

```
type Primitive = string | Function | number | boolean | Symbol | undefined | null 
type DeepOmitHelper<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: //extra level of indirection needed to trigger homomorhic behavior 
        T[P] extends infer TP ? // distribute over unions
        TP extends Primitive ? TP : // leave primitives and functions alone
        TP extends any[] ? DeepOmitArray<TP, K> : // Array special handling
        DeepOmit<TP, K> 
        : never
}
type DeepOmit<T, K> = T extends Primitive ? T : DeepOmitHelper<T,Exclude<keyof T, K>> 

type DeepOmitArray<T extends any[], K> = {
    [P in keyof T]: DeepOmit<T[P], K>
}
type Input =  {
    __typename: string,
    a: string,
    nested: {
        __typename: string,
        b: string
    }
    nestedArray: Array<{
        __typename: string,
        b: string
    }>
    nestedTuple: [{
        __typename: string,
        b: string
    }]
}

type InputWithoutKey = DeepOmit<Input, '__typename'>

let s: InputWithoutKey = {
    a: "",
    nested: {
        b:""
    },
    nestedArray: [
        {b: ""}
    ],
    nestedTuple: [
        { b: ""},
    ]
}
```

Just a caveat, this works on 3.4, the handling of mapped types on arrays and tuples has changed recently, so depending on version you might need to handle arrays as a special case.

Comment: Really great solution! I am running into one issue though where it looks like `DeepOmit` turns optional properties into required ones. Is there any way to prevent that?

The below code snippet complains that `test` does not have the `world` property

type Input =  {
    __typename: string,
    hello: string
    world?: string
}

type InputWithoutKey = DeepOmit<Input, '__typename'>

let test: InputWithoutKey = {
    hello: "hello",
}

Comment: Another issue I found was that `DeepOmit<string, "__typename">` is not equivalent to `string`, so if you try to pass a value that ran through `DeepOmit` into a function that accepts a `string` it will raise a typerror: type OmitString = DeepOmit<string, "__typename">
let y: OmitString = "great"

function cool(z: string) {
    return z
}

cool(y)

Comment: Expanding on the last comment, it's an issue that comes up when working with an array of strings. This results in a type error because it is applying DeepOmit to type string, which doesn't equal type string.
type Type1 = {
    __typename: string,
    arr: string[]
}

type TypeOmit = DeepOmit<Type1, "__typename">

let x: TypeOmit = {
    arr: ["great", "breat"]
}

let z: string[] = x.arr

Comment: @TLadd edited, fixed your issues, let me know if you find anything else, glad to see the type is getting good use :)

Comment: Might just be me, but this isn't working for me on TS 3.5.

Comment: How does just moving `Exclude<keyof T, K>` outside preserve the optional types?

Answer (score 12):

The answers here were inspiring. I had some small issues with TypeScript 4.0 that I was able to work out. I'm maintaining it as a gist: https://gist.github.com/ahuggins-nhs/826906a58e4c1e59306bc0792e7826d1. Hope this helps some people, especially those wanting to deal with Partial utility in a deep omit.

```
/** Union of primitives to skip with deep omit utilities. */
type Primitive = string | Function | number | boolean | Symbol | undefined | null

/** Deeply omit members of an array of interface or array of type. */
export type DeepOmitArray<T extends any[], K> = {
    [P in keyof T]: DeepOmit<T[P], K>
}

/** Deeply omit members of an interface or type. */
export type DeepOmit<T, K> = T extends Primitive ? T : {
    [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: //extra level of indirection needed to trigger homomorhic behavior
        T[P] extends infer TP ? // distribute over unions
        TP extends Primitive ? TP : // leave primitives and functions alone
        TP extends any[] ? DeepOmitArray<TP, K> : // Array special handling
        DeepOmit<TP, K>
        : never
}

/** Deeply omit members of an array of interface or array of type, making all members optional. */
export type PartialDeepOmitArray<T extends any[], K> = Partial<{
    [P in Partial<keyof T>]: Partial<PartialDeepOmit<T[P], K>>
}>

/** Deeply omit members of an interface or type, making all members optional. */
export type PartialDeepOmit<T, K> = T extends Primitive ? T : Partial<{
    [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: //extra level of indirection needed to trigger homomorhic behavior
        T[P] extends infer TP ? // distribute over unions
        TP extends Primitive ? TP : // leave primitives and functions alone
        TP extends any[] ? PartialDeepOmitArray<TP, K> : // Array special handling
        Partial<PartialDeepOmit<TP, K>>
        : never
}>
```

Comment: could you provide a simple example using this?

Comment: Thank You I was using typescript 4 and 
I was a bit confused with first answer !!

Answer (score 7):

For those coming here with a later version of TS (I've tested this with TS3.8.3), you'll need to inline `DeepOmitHelper` from [Titian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir)'s answer.

```js
type Primitive =
  | string
  | Function
  | number
  | boolean
  | Symbol
  | undefined
  | null;

type DeepOmitArray<T extends any[], K> = {
  [P in keyof T]: DeepOmit<T[P], K>;
};

export type DeepOmit<T, K> = T extends Primitive
  ? T
  : {
      [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P] extends infer TP
        ? TP extends Primitive
          ? TP // leave primitives and functions alone
          : TP extends any[]
          ? DeepOmitArray<TP, K> // Array special handling
          : DeepOmit<TP, K>
        : never;
    };
```

Comment: I'm trying to adapt this to make a deep property optional (Partial), instead of omitting it, but am struggling.