# Typescript - Some omit implementations remove optionality from properties

Tags: typescript

I've written several implementations of `Omit`, including the one shown by Intellisense when hovering over `Omit` itself. I'm running into difficulty understanding **why some implementations are homomorphic and others are not**.

I've found that:

- The implementation shown when hovering over `Omit` is not the correct one
- The implementation shown when hovering over `Omit` does not preserve the 'optionality' of properties (i.e. is not homomorphic), and is therefore different than the real implementation, which does preserve 'optionality'.
- Two other implementations I've written are also not-homomorphic, and I can't understand why.

Here's my code:

```js
// a type with optional and readonly properties
type HasOptional = { a: number; b?: number, c: string; d?: readonly string[]; };

// first attempt
type Omit_1<T, K extends keyof T> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P]; };
type Omit_1_Optional = Omit_1<HasOptional, 'a'>; // b, d lost optionality

// Omit's 'fake' implementation, as shown by Intellisense
type Omit_2<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P]; };
type Omit_2_Optional = Omit_2<HasOptional, 'a'>; // b, d lost optionality

// Using Omit itself
type Omit_3<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = Omit<T, K>;
type Omit_3_Optional = Omit_3<HasOptional, 'a'>; // optionality maintained!

// Writing Omit's implementation explicitly
type Omit_4<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type Omit_4_Optional = Omit_4<HasOptional, 'a'>; // optionality maintained!
```

I've seen [here, in an answer about deep Omit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539387/deep-omit-with-typescript) that `[P in K]:` is used as an extra level of indirection to cause homomorphic behavior, but that's also present here and yet the first two implementations don't preserve 'optionality'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mapped type is considered homomorphic in two cases. Either we map over `keyof T`( [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12563)) or we map over a type parameter `K` where `K` has a constraint of `keyof T` (`K extends keyof T`, [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12826)).

While `Exclude<keyof T, K>` does extend `keyof T` is does not fit into these two specific cases. This means that mapping directly over `Exclude<keyof T, K>` will not produce a homomorphic mapped type. If we take `Exclude<keyof T, K>` and put it into a type parameter that has the required constraint then we get the desired behavior.

```
// a type with optional and readonly properties
type HasOptional = { a: number; b?: number, c: string; d?: readonly string[]; };

// mapping over Exclude<keyof T, K> optionality lost
type Omit_1<T, K extends keyof T> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P]; };
type Omit_1_Optional = Omit_1<HasOptional, 'a'>; // b, d lost optionality

// mapping over Exclude<keyof T, K> optionality lost
type Omit_2<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P]; };
type Omit_2_Optional = Omit_2<HasOptional, 'a'>; // b, d lost optionality

// Omit in 3.5 has homomorphic behavior since it uses Pick which is  homomorphic 
type Omit_3<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = Omit<T, K>;
type Omit_3_Optional = Omit_3<HasOptional, 'a'>; // optionality maintained!

// has homomorphic behavior since it uses Pick which is  homomorphic
type Omit_4<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type Omit_4_Optional = Omit_4<HasOptional, 'a'>; // optionality maintained!
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
What I don't quite grasp is _why_ `Exclude<keyof T, K>`, while extending `keyof T`, doesn't fit these cases. It looks like `Pick` does exactly the same as the first implementation - it maps over the same things, it just specifies that the second generic parameter `extends keyof T`.

I can be satisfied however with knowing that `Pick` is homomorphic and to use that.

Comment: Another issue I have with my implementation not working is that while it's not homomorphic, the type hints are explicit, and the ones for `Omit_3` and `Omit_4` are not, because they use `Pick<>...` as part of the description.

Comment: @RanLottem It's not homomorphic because while it does extend `keyof T` it is not one of those EXACT cases. It's not that we must map over something that extends `keyof T` it must either be `keyof T `or a type parameter with a `keyof T` constraint. nothing else will trigger the homomorphic behavior.

Comment: @RanLottem With regard to the tooltip displayed that is a bit of a heuristic the compiler uses. If the type is just an alias for another type it will display the alias (in this case `Pick<Type, Exclude...>` if it is a mapped type it will not be expanded. For conditionals it depends but they will usually be resolved and the result displayed .. not all of the rules are 100% clear to me either.