# Typescript: Omitting Object "Levels" in "Deep" Object Types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given an API that can provide "expanded" versions of an object graph, I'm looking to get a simple way of defining the types returned.

As an example, for the these definitions

```js
interface A {
  id: string;
  q: string;
  b: B;
  cs: C[];
}

interface B {
  id: string;
  prev: B;
  c: C;
}

interface C {
  id: string;
  foo: string;
  ds: D[];
}

interface D {
  id: string;
  e: E;
}

interface E {
  id: string;
}
```

I would need to derive e.g. the following types

```js
type A0 = {
  id: string,
  q: string,
  b: { id: string },
  cs: Array<{id: string}>,
};

type A1 = {
  id: string,
  q: string,
  b: {
    id: string,
    prev: { id: string },
    c: { id: string },
  },
  cs: Array<{
    id: string,
    foo: string,
    ds: Array<{id: string}>,
  }>,
};

type A2 = {
  id: string,
  q: string,
  b: {
    id: string,
    prev: {
      id: string,
      prev: { id: string },
      c: { id: string },
    },
    c: {
      id: string,
      foo: string,
      ds: Array<{
        id: string,
      }>,
    },
  },
  cs: Array<{
    id: string,
    foo: string,
    ds: Array<{
      id: string,
      e: { id: string},
    }>,
  }>,
};
```

What I have are the following types (and so on for larger levels)

```js
export type Retain0Levels<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]:
    T[P] extends infer TP
    ? TP extends Primitive
      ? TP
      : TP extends any[]
        ? Array<{ id: string }>
        : { id: string }
   : never
};

export type Retain1Level<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]:
    T[P] extends infer TP
    ? TP extends Primitive
      ? TP
      : TP extends any[]
        ? { [I in keyof TP]: Retain0Levels<TP[I]> }
        : Retain0Levels<TP>
    : never
};

export type Retain2Levels<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]:
    T[P] extends infer TP
    ? TP extends Primitive
      ? TP
      : TP extends any[]
        ? { [I in keyof TP]: Retain1Level<TP[I]> }
        : Retain1Level<TP>
    : never
};

type Primitive = string | Function | number | boolean | symbol | undefined | null;
```

This works fine, but there are of course two problems with this:

1. I have to define a type for each level. It would be nice to have just two types (I assume one doesn't work or would get very messy): a leaf (level0) and a recursively defined higher order level.
2. the consumer of my API access handler has to cast the return type (e.g. `A`) to the type they requested (by providing a parameter indicating how many levels to expand). It would be nice to have the return type based on the input parameter provided.

As an example for (2), say we have a function that calls backend API, e.g. `getAs(levels: number): A[]`. I'd like this to be `getAs(levels: number): Array<RetainLevels<A, levels>>` (or similar). If it isn't, the consumer has to call the method with e.g. `getAs(5) as RetainLevels<A, 5>`.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to improve what I currently have to solve (one of) the above problems?

P.S. Kudos to [@titian-cernicova-dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir)
 from who's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539616/7159043) I derived what I currently have

#### Edited

Corrected mistake as pointed out by @jcalz and added an example for "dynamic return type" use case based on the type defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your type definitions less repetitive I'd suggest something like this:

```
type PrevNum = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17];
// lengthen as needed

export type RetainLevel<N extends number, T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends infer TP
    ? TP extends Primitive
      ? TP
      : TP extends any[] ? { [I in keyof TP]: Rec<N, TP[I]> } : Rec<N, TP>
    : never
};

type Rec<N extends number, T> = N extends 0
  ? { id: string }
  : RetainLevel<PrevNum[N], T>;
```

This allows you to specify types like `RetainLevel<10, XXX>` instead of `Retain10Level<XXX>`.  TypeScript doesn't really let you do type-level arithmetic, so there's no way to subtract one from an arbitrary number.  The `PrevNum` tuple is probably good enough, though; you can make it as long as whatever you deem the largest reasonable value people will ask for.

---

Testing to see if this gives the types you've specified:

```
type MutuallyExtends<T extends U, U extends V, V = T> = true;

type A0 = RetainLevel<0, A>;
type A0Okay = MutuallyExtends<A0, A0Manual>; // okay

type A1 = RetainLevel<1, A>;
type A1Okay = MutuallyExtends<A1, A1Manual>; // okay
```

These look okay.

```
type A2 = RetainLevel<2, A>;
type A2Okay = MutuallyExtends<A2, A2Manual>; // error?
```

Looks like your `A2` type isn't the same as `RetainLevel<2, A>`.  Although I checked that your `Retain2Levels<A>` is the same as `RetainLevel<2, A>`, so I guess your code doesn't quite constitute a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I'm going to assume it's okay.

---

As for the casting part, please put an example of what you mean in your code, and then maybe I or someone else will be able to answer that.  If you mean that the number is passed in as a parameter, the above might help if you make the function generic in `N`, the type of that number.  Seems like a separate question, maybe, but you're the boss!

**UPDATE**: seeing your example for `getAs()`, yes, now that `RetainLevel` is generic in the number `N`, you can make `getAs()` generic also:

```
declare function getAs<N extends number>(levels: N): Array<RetainLevel<N, A>>;
```

This should work the way you want:

```
const a0s = getAs(0); // Array<RetainLevel<0, A>>, same as Array<A0>
const a1s = getAs(1); // Array<RetainLevel<1, A>>, same as Array<A1>
const a10s = getAs(10); // Array<RetainLevel<10, A>>;
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnOAEwC5kBnMKUAcwG4dkBHYsikGugI2ICFbcETiAYQDaAXVoBfLFlCRYiFF0x0CTclV7IADlAgA3bpoRDJ02dHhJkg5blWl1rTTAD2LtSza58A5ABExUxlwCwV-WzwiB09NCGIAUSDzeSt4iPtmDSwpLDAATy0UVAAGAFk4EABXOAAbZABedKjMpzpGaKzcTkxIjypkCSNfVCgoODyAHgxejtYBgD5JWlyCooBGcqrahqa+1tx2lq9kbuxcO2bHY9wdfWJpjKuBzT57maPnukG6fmIRscmZ3OjxidFwrncs2uyB8f1G4ym7yeEkWX1R3xWhTQACZNtU6o0gSDOgw9sdTmCkaDztpdAYIjTifsabS7j0mZRPizkMZ2ZdPFzzt8abygYz+SSaRCyS9zrC0PDAZTxTLledRVT+sKWSjZdrtb8FQCppSObLpVDZfL-gixcCJcyaXE+WTBbhdWiltJ8liAAoUAC2wDAwD0KHqdAAPlCo8gAGKVEAIEMuECxqoB9jQWPsNw1CAVWMkPKZlw1WOJ-AQGCgCD4dOVGo1ZY+lD+-QAOUqAZ2wgAtGsADTFQdD7GDgDMg4ALIOAKyDgBsg4A7IOAByDgCco5HayHa3Hayna1nawXa2XaxX4iwAHo78gIAAPSAgfDIOAkZAgCB1uvSC+WguFAYDIK2yAAEoQGAcCgAAMvoEA1BMHZPq+EDvt+GZZlAg7IAAKvMOx2sIvp4CAyAANYQHkLgwIRojEARZGiOhb4+BRMDQIRvpqgA-Lx7GYZx-rAEGIZhmquCCQRfHcrgzHkS+HHfhUeRiMggnTMIACSFHUbR9G8UxUEQAgqH4XJemiMREjIMQ0EWR2Vm+vMarEL+YZQF80iYigTmocJWE-t2uFWcRjRoSpInfsUdDaZqcxSIpZmwQhSEoe2ehdgGwgdqIEXLFWCA1HAujIDAibJsAqbIJQMGoCQQUxSFOHQPMAAU+ZhjUvgdgAlHCxrQelICIb1lloPMqJYAgqZkJ+xTfo0DVgE1nXFAN1DIA+RoIqNcHjZlEwjtN8z4SQcABigX77ZMJTufNICLXAawrfVjUkJ1azbbtj42pMh0ZZNQ7nZd123d+gMTKgaxPQtYFvctOxrRtaxbTte0w8Dx2g2dqAzS2qzIKUlRgPiNR5PEGFYRMBHBZxACq+FM4z34AGr4RzOxETs5CVBAxNYiUOy4xNyGnfhhO0BBJQAPJUeMOxkxTtRUzTqmwwTZQVPis1y2sYswUdEsoWDMv+WgayK8rjSq5T1O0z4sMWxseu1AbJOoNixtjWbEzjtNsve9itt5Cr5OO5rsWw0HPt4p7WOPtAUAgfxWBAA)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz for your great example! The use of array indexes to "simulate" decreasing numbers is clever ;-) I've amended the example (A2 was indeed wrong, stupid copy / paste error) and added an example for the method invocation part as requested.

I don't assume there will be anything better, but I'll hold off accepting your answer for a short while.

Comment: Great, thanks! I still don't quite seem to have wrapped my head around primitives as types, could have gotten that second part myself...

Comment: One thing, though: I believe now your `Rec` does not deal with arrays of primitives correctly (there wasn't anything in my example, so my bad). I've changed it, replacing `{ id: string }` with `T extends Primitive ? T : { id: string }` and all seems fine. Thanks again!