# Why doesn't TypeScript pick up fact that I add back missing property to object in this example, how to fix?

Tags: typescript

I have [this TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwG4QE7CgXigbwFBRQCWCYArsAFy4GFQBmcqAtgIZVQDOwqJA5rUL0iAGwjV8dOmHYALat14IBUgL611hOBXIdJdRi3YKe-QQ1EQA-JXOEAPrigBjRMAgIOAIRFwARlCqUHZQjjhQMsDyXKbKgRp46ngA9MlQqBBgIqzOEJxQ2sC6AHTCYsWunh4YAO5EUQU6FKWWxZGyeKCQUADyTcAAsnAAJlg0Wv0S5mXi41IRciZKKnSa8Un0ZAjOwESILogo6AA8ACpQEAAe7gjD+fDIaMAAfAAUYKhwYJzUpwCUc0q3EaGGwzl8CAgPTAu0QnDObw+X04fzwtCI9CgrwAhIVioUSjNQo5sa8AOTtMnEBAg-H9FpiP4A-QTYB0orNInYcLtahkxhwNrDehUtZJQgZYBkVA0wqJNFAjCFMaVI7AV76Ei6KZSQxsDgU4VkgA000sOvmvKgZK1zTARvMYtNrO1cyETH1fLAyhNZrEFqklRuHEhNSgPn8rwA2mTinGyQBdVFqBKqVF4PEEzmtdpQVJQWRwMPAOBQNgAa2gUSI+QQcAwUU+YdYNLQn1QVjRVzATAwm22sJp4MQUJhewQ8POVxudwKfgAVhAdm9Lr9mbRFVAQL8xjhxb0F0u2ZWQJxXpc-qUmABRHKyV4IVjMaCYZ5ug4TjBIVgiMgvqCXFGj7PgmaJSPmAD6xQ1gACtkJA9IeOzUlAvjDKwnCyOkEA-iIIBxsU5gYliXQQHAmLfr+L6YNgZL+IuOxkuu8xbkBT4QAmKoQqOg5npRf7JqsFwiJw0AsnQIBsSBYz8RAjoaOmEoQFKMpbokQA), demonstrating an error where TypeScript is not picking up the fact that I added a property to an object.

```
type Convert = {
  input: {
    format: string
    file: {
      path: string
    }
  }
  output: {
    format: string
    file?:
      | { content: Blob } 
      | { path: string }
  }
}

// replaces output.file.content with output.file.path
type OutputMod = {
  output: {
    file: {
      path: string
    }
  }
}

function convert<T extends Convert>(props: T) {
  const out = cloneOptions<T>(props)

  if (!out.output.file || !('path' in out.output.file)) {
    out.output.file = { path: 'foo.pdf' }
  }

  return out
}

const out = convert({
  input: {
    format: 'pdf',
    file: {
      path: 'input.pdf'
    }
  },
  output: {
    format: 'png',
    file: {
      content: new Blob(['...'])
    }
  }
})

out.output.file.path // how to make this not throw an error?

export function cloneOptions<T extends object>(x: T) {
  const y: T = {}

  Object.keys(x).forEach(name => {
    const value = x[name]

    // _.isPlainObject in lodash really...
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      y[name] = cloneOptions(value)
    } else {
      y[name] = value
    }
  })

  return y
}
```

I tried using [Typescript: Omit nested property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884720/typescript-omit-nested-property/67888086#67888086) to do [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBAlEBnKAbANxAEkA7CAVzgDFYBhKUo+LAWyjnQF4EBvYBAggBDOAAsAygGMoaAPwAuBNjgwAlqQDmAhBspwl-QYIBmsVqKUr1WnabV4QV1Ru2CAvjqhV9huwjMYCwNlF1tjAIcQRVCbNwRPT1BIWERhbGRSKQCKLLg1RgQYHHwiMn1aGAYmEBYQdk4AOSgAExAAHh0AFQRwTlIW7EwSwhJyKkrq5jg2DhAAGmAAPgAKHT0qJS7FgEolAAUYKFY1bA6dAHkTuAAhZHbthAkIPDU4doBybzh9D6WlhAAMj4-m+vj4kUchiEojEzjiCQSOk8AP4-hkpFwjgAdHgoJoVhs4Dt-MU4BQYKQEIdjqcQNjiliiITxsTgEkUGgEABBBA8IzGYQxAURQQAI3hrn8ESkkvCxk8ETAflFxmQSlIFFYYtq0uMAC8NVqdTBFqrBAB3FXmiIUI3a3U2xUK9nATnoQ5qa5qIhDHjWVwIAA+CE1DpgwYQYqg+BAwipIYy2vwwGAAHoAFQZgQZhAAcRAaTweAQBGErxaoZwnErInEOAQUBMjbFACsQFI4Dm027UOhucWaRBsO0Lm35gg6MIpGJ0H0QAMhtyYDBhPdPd7fQCeABtAC62-8Y9bvTA-UG1PUm4bckn09nCGtqp3Q90VIA1iBkE2EMe9wo9UEEMd2xUCpxnBZL1kPcEDTNMEHaABaZCUN0RBsDEbw8ErHUEFyApSDUfUQErC03jEIoOwpbACIQKRyzwQDIwHPAhxHY8XyOCA9wnECwPvSChwPfx3B3T9v2bP9U3dBAAAk4xaB5T3PIYsGEFpGDwZBl1Xe542Qf4+X8Hp50XBB938W9SBAZh-C2ZSFwvHcNBMWo5IUvdLPc9S7IQEyz0coZnNIVyI3k9SJ1A7EXLcgB9TyIlvcKWl86zbOkvs-OEBwlNMi81I00gtJ0td2n0wyuGMhyzIsxLzIS4x7LyoKYojeKvNqxq-OqpzWoQWLItAvqsBUBrBFvEauwiDUbN1XsuQAGXSd5-JU4Z1M07SV1K8rtz8ncPkcLRxA+GDmoQABGBBb1UCh0CUExyzOVN5vQK43hudIOmPCd9lhHrVIUzaSr00gDMPCIlpUdo-vEAFztukAvJFUVONkN8EAAUTAKQ8AoNp2nEn8fu8xTYbEf5-1-Ns0e4kTHxBG1aYxonJLbKn3tuL7RxpoSJy6bK8Bh2F-hEjKuU5u4edbCcAGkvyGc6WLY6WKt-a5PrOaW5YVpZxfQEaKDwRAeEl+5uXmA7hA+CcPjFU6ATgxt3314ZsCNuAACY+XVj7zctu2Hdg+DwDQTsSN6FdYGxRsYDaCMMKwnD0AgRlaiIFLXeeV53gkVQJ3Ah9zoDLR9x9-cIeMPOI3OgADAASXg+oAWULTCWncbFG+G6t3Frrzs7edpJt4qLC8g1vxFaYTpqeVQAYQBum5CtyobgPuOrHgSJzX+YxoZtLHWMV6EAAdXIgARDg-V925-aeF4h4+YRsXtwynagd8gA):

```
export async function resolveInputForConvertRemoteNode<
  T extends ResolveInputForConvertRemote,
>(
  input: T,
): Promise<
  OmitBy<T, Split<'output'>> & {
    output: { file: { path: string } }
  }
> {
    console.log(input)
    return Promise.resolve(input)
}
```

But that comes with more complex errors.

How do I make it so I can replace the props (sometimes more than one nested prop) on a TypeScript input? Specifically in that implementation of the types in the `convert` function.

P.S. Sidenote: I disabled `noImplicitAny` to get the `cloneOptions` function to work, so not sure how to improve that if possible.

If I try this:

```
function convert<T extends Convert>(props: T): T & OutputMod { ... }
```

I get:

```
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T & OutputMod'.
  Type 'Convert' is not assignable to type 'T & OutputMod'.
    Type 'Convert' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'Convert' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Convert'.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'OutputMod'.
          Type 'Convert' is not assignable to type 'OutputMod'.
            The types of 'output.file' are incompatible between these types.
              Type '{ content: Blob; } | { path: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ path: string; }'.
                Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ path: string; }'.(2322)
```

Comment: `out` is of type `T`, and there's no way to convince the compiler otherwise unless you start asserting or writing type guard functions. I'd suggest you just assert as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOXE6N). If you need to replace props programmatically then you'll need to write a type function that does some kind of merge, but that's going to have lots of edge cases and is likely out of scope for this SO question. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah what you did should be fine, kind of verbose but it gets the job done. Thanks.

Comment: I'll write an answer when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `convert`, the variable `out` is just of type `T` and does not mutate even if you set one of its properties. TypeScript doesn't really model when the type of a value changes (except for certain types of [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html), but only if you are directly assigning to a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), and `{content: Blob} | {path: string}` is not one of those).

In fact the compiler probably shouldn't let you assign to `out.output.file` at all because it doesn't know that `T` has one of those, but it takes the shortcut of widening generics to their [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) and doesn't notice.

---

Anyway since there's no hope of getting the compiler to follow what you're doing, you'll need to figure out the appropriate output type yourself and then [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that it's of that type.  Here's one way to do it:

```
function convert<T extends Convert>(props: T) {
  const out = cloneOptions<T>(props)

  if (!out.output.file || !('path' in out.output.file)) {
    out.output.file = { path: 'foo.pdf' }
  }

  return out as
    Omit<T, "output"> & {
      output: Omit<T["output"], "file"> & {
        file: { path: string }
      }
    }
}
```

That type is just the result of me walking through the logic and representing what's been done.  It's possible that you might be able to refactor property setting code into something that calculates the type *for* you, but that could be complicated and depends strongly on the particular operations performed and the use cases you need to support. For this example it's just easier to say that the output is "everything in `T` except for `output`, and everything in `output` except for `file`, which is now known to be `{path: string}`."

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwG4QE7CgXigbwFBRQCWCYArsAFy4GFQBmcqAtgIZVQDOwqJA5rUL0iAGwjV8dOmHYALat14IBUgL611hOBXIdJdRi3YKe-QQ1EQA-JXMAfXFADGiYBAQcAQiLgAjKJp0DjhQMsDyXKbKARp46ngA9AlQqBBgIqxOEJxQ2sC6AHTCYgUuHu4YAO5E4bk6FEWWBWGyeKCQUADy9cAAsnAAJlg0Wj0S5sXiI1KhciZKKnSB6vH0ZAhOwESIzogo6AA8ACpQEAAebggDOfDIaMAAfAAUYKhwYJzURwCU02XcdQw2CcPgQEE6YC2iE4x2er3enG+eFoRHoUCeAEI8gU8oVJlA7A4MU8AOQtEnEBCAnE9Rpib6-fSjYA0-INfHYEItagkxhwZoDegU5bI5GEVLAMioKl5KCsTjmTrMGrHAA0UAARLiKBqHlAAGTTKTajhKlVHADaWp6GoAuuqNZNdQajTNJhJZuF5vwYjNfUs4sj-hhZcC9vcnvoSLpxlJDGwOGTBSTVRNLLGZtyoCTow0wMnzMtU8yY6748Zs2BlCm02IM1IypcOGDKlBvH4nhaSQUeyTbUi1LFVEi8NiTXSIM05FAklBZHBW8A4FA2ABraDhIg5BBwDDhN6t1hUtBvVBWZHnMBMDBrDZQqkgxDgyHbBAwk7nS7XXK+ABWEE2Z4zi+RlaGDKAQGGHBVDlHIjjFLo-wAll1xATgnjOb4iiYABRTJZCeBBWGYaBMD1JldjfDAkFYEQyFIqAzgtIiSNtBDCFnAB9AotwABQyEhOiQzZKSgHwBnlWQUggWiRBAHsCnMVF0XaCA4DRGi6NIzBsBJPx-02ElQL9EBmOIiBbWGR8wQhe90M0+iByWU4RE4aAKMIUyWIs4YHIgQsNBHcUIElaUILiIA)